# How do I make a web site on my own PC, without DNS, available to others?

Tags: web-hosting, iis7, iis

I thought if I removed the host name from the site's binding, like the Default Web Site, just my machine name in the URL would work, but I replaced the binding, and thought my machine name/IP address, plus the host name bound to the site, would work, but it doesn't. I would just like a colleague to have access for testing.

I am running IIS 8 on Windows 8. I have a hosts file entry with the URL host name pointing to localhost, like I always do for web sites on remote servers.

Comment: Looks like your missing one step, router... port forwarding. Your IP address internally will be NAT a internal IP. You need to tell your router to forward port 80 to the internal IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need an entry in the hosts file on your colleague's computer or a DNS record pointing to your computer. You can't do it based solely on the hosts file entry on your computer, because your colleague's computer doesn't (and can't) look at that file.

Comment: I have a DNS record pointing to my machine. All of us on the domain do, but just seeing my machine and not reading its hosts file is probably where it stops. I expected IIS to read the host file, but it probably gets read first to redirect back to the site on IIS.